# Jquery clone date picker value is not getting selected in the field

Tags: jquery, clone

I have tried to select a date in the date picker column while cloning and whenever I select the date it is not getting selected. It affects only the first parent row. **Cloning and all working fine**, and **whenever I select the date picker it only selects and shows the value only in the first row**. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    $('.add_field_button').click(function () {
    var ab = $('.row_duplicate_remove').clone(true);
    var row_id =$('.row_duplicate:last').attr('row_id');
    $('input.datefield').datepicker();
      ab.attr('row_id',Number(row_id)+1)
      ab.removeClass('row_duplicate_remove');
      ab.find('.remove').show();
      var nxt = Number(row_id)+1;
      ab.find('.mydatepicker_new').attr('id','received_on_'+nxt);
      ab.find('input,select').val('');
      ab.find('#received_on_'+nxt).datepicker({
          autoclose: true,
          todayHighlight: true
      });
      $('.clonediv').append(ab);
    event.preventDefault();
    });
    // Date Picker
    jQuery('#received_on_1').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    });

 <button class="add_field_button btn btn-warning">Add</button>
<div class="input-group small-text w-100">
                        <input type="text"  name="received_on" id="received_on_1"  class="form-control mydatepicker_new" placeholder="--Select Date(s)--">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text "><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
ab.find('.mydatepicker_new')
      .removeData('datepicker')
      .attr('id', 'received_on_'+nxt)
      .unbind()
      .datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
```

This one worked for me